# How to prove that: if A$B=1$ then $IX< \frac{1}{26}$?

Tags: geometry

Let $I$ is incenter of triangle ABC and $ D,E,F,X$ are incenter of triangles $A B I, B C I, C A I, D E F$. How to prove that: if  A$B=1$ then $IX< \frac{1}{26}$? Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Just a work in progress, since I believe this problem will take some time.

---

For first, let we set $\widehat{BAC}=4\alpha,\widehat{ABC}=4\beta,\widehat{ACB}=4\gamma$ and let $r_A,r_B,r_C$ be the inradii of $IBC,IAC,IAB$. Since $r_A\cot\beta+r_A\cot\gamma = a = r\cot(2\beta)+r\cot(2\gamma)$, we have:

$$ r_A = r \cdot\frac{\cos(\beta+\gamma)}{2\cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)} = r\cdot\frac{\cos(\beta+\gamma)}{\cos(\beta-\gamma)+\cos(\beta+\gamma)}$$
and so on. We also have $\widehat{BID}=\widehat{CID}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta-\gamma=\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha$, hence $\widehat{DIE}=\frac{3\pi}{4}-\gamma$ 
and: 
$$IE=\frac{r_A}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha\right)}=\frac{r_A}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha\right)}=\frac{r_A}{\cos(\beta+\gamma)}=\frac{r}{2\cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)}.$$
Now it shouldn't be too difficult to bound $IX^2$.